# I have a "META-INF/androidx.legacy_legacy-support-core-utils.version"Error . How can ı solve my problem

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I want get generate singed apk then I have **"META-INF/androidx.legacy_legacy-support-core-utils.version"** error .
How can ı solve my problem .

**Build Gradle(app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.viadom"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

Comment: add `exclude 'META-INF/androidx.legacy_legacy-support-core-utils.version'`

Comment: I dont know where to add it

Comment: `buildTypes {

   ....................
        
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/androidx.legacy_legacy-support-core-utils.version'
        }
    }`

Comment: I have **Entry name 'META-INF/androidx.vectordrawable_vectordrawable.version' collided** error now

Comment: clean-rebuild-restart

Comment: there isnt work on me I have  **Entry name 'META-INF/androidx.vectordrawable_vectordrawable.version' collided** error

Comment: there isnt work on me I have Entry name 'META-INF/androidx.vectordrawable_vectordrawable.version' collided error

Comment: `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add packageOptions to you build.gradle file under android block.

```
android {
   
   ...

   packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'META-INF/androidx.legacy_legacy-support-core-utils.version'
   }

}
```